# Will a jquery method called on a jquery object always return the same object?

Tags: jquery

From jquery site :

**Methods called on jQuery selections are in the $.fn namespace, and automatically receive and return the selection as 'this'.**

but if i use  **$('selector').clone()** ,won't the returned object be the cloned one rather than the original? In general,how to know what will be the return object of a jquery method?

Comment: See the method documentation.

Comment: In general, always read the documentation when you have a question.

Comment: but I am quoting jquery.com here.

Comment: Would it make sense to return the original object?

Comment: Based on the examples in [**the documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) (and common sense) it looks like the returned jQuery object is the _cloned_ object, not the original.  There's only one place to look for this... the documentation.

Comment: The definitive reference is the source code. Especially in a case like this where the documentation is suspect to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For `clone()`, the documentation you quote looks wrong.

[The end of the `clone()` implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d837f119c3729565103005d5d7fa89e1dd8110cb/src/manipulation.js#L186) clearly states that it is the cloned set that is returned.

```
jQuery.extend({
  clone: function( elem, dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents ) {
    var i, l, srcElements, destElements,
    clone = elem.cloneNode( true ),

    // --- Stuff removed for brevity ---

    // Return the cloned set
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: hi anders,I was quoting http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/

but I guess maybe I misinterpreted and what they meant was object methods always return 'this'.Now 'this' could refer to any object varying according to the method.For ex-this refers to cloned object for clone() .

I still might be wrong though.

Comment: I think that they didn't quite think of `clone()` when they wrote that sentence. In general it's true though, but with `clone()` (and maybe more?) as an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Idea here is that you can chain jquery methods. Some of the methods might change selection and some not, but they have to return the set, so they can be chained. For instance

```
$('.pages').filter('.inactive').hide().end().filter('.active').show()
```

In this case method `hide` will receive selection as `this` and will do what it is supposed to do and return `this` unchanged.

But `filter` method on the opposite will receive full selection but will change it and returned changed selection as `this`.

Really cool thing to notice here is that you can actually use `end` to get previous selection to do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question at OP accurately, requirement to determine which `object` returned ? Whether `original` or `clone` ?

For `element`, or `selector` clones , `clone` object do not appear to possess `selector` property at `object` that returns `> 0` , i.e.g., try

```
$(function () {

    var original = $("div");
    var clone = $("div").clone(true, true);

    console.log(original.selector.length > 0, clone.selector.length > 0);
    // `true` , `false`

    $.fn.isClone = function () {
        return !$(this).selector.length > 0
    };

    console.log($(clone).isClone(), $(original).isClone());
    // `true` , `false`
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/LZaTM/